# Facebook Like Button: how to like an image file url?

Tags: facebook, api, url

I want to have it so the Facebook Like Button API is able to 'Like' and image hosted on a server. EG if it can 'Like' something like: `mysite.com/photo1.jpg`

Currently, this does not work with the API:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mysite.com/photo1.jpg" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Does anyone know of a work around for this? Or do I need to put each image on an HTML page?

Comment: possible duplicate (resp. continuation) of [Facebook Like Button API - Like different URL to page button is on?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12135193/facebook-like-button-api-like-different-url-to-page-button-is-on)

Answer (score 0):

Get the iframe of like button from the below link and in that rewrite 
href="http://mysite.com/photo1.jpg"

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050786/how-to-add-a-facebook-like-button-to-blogger-blog-post/12055011#12055011
```

Try this it will work